# Displaying JSON using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am having problem in displaying the nested objects within the JSON structure into the a page using JQuery. I'm using JQuery's function (.getJSON),  but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the JSON file below:

```
{
"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
            },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
            },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
           }
        }
}
```

And this is the Javascript file that uses JQuery to access the JSON objects:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#letter-w a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON('widget.json', function (data) {
            var html = '';
            html += data.widget.debug;
            html += data.widget.window.title;
            html += data.widget.window.name;
        });
        $('#output').html(html);
    });
});
```

In the above code, #letter-w is a id for a link that when clicked displays the result and #output is the div where the output/results will be displayed within the HTML page itself. Also, for the sake of checking, I've only written 2-3 lines to access the JSON objects.
P.S JSON is very confusing since you've to takecare of all the braces and all.
Any suggestions or help would be grateful. Thanks in-advance!

Comment: Is your selector correct? You say `#letter-w` is an anchor, but you're selecting `#letter-w a` which will look for an anchor within `#letter-w`.

Comment: @MrCode Oh yeah, it is an anchor tag (a-href)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is in the wrong place:

```
$('#output').html(html);
```

It is outside of the callback and so this actually executes before the JSON is retrieved and parsed because the AJAX is asynchronous. Move it into the callback:

```
$.getJSON('widget.json', function (data) {
    var html = '';
    html += data.widget.debug;
    html += data.widget.window.title;
    html += data.widget.window.name;
    $('#output').html(html);
});
```

Also check my comment, it looks like your selector should be changed to `#letter-w` such as:

```
$('#letter-w').click
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Yeah, that was my mistake. @MrCode One quick question, do I have to use a loop here in this case to display the objects or just directly one by one display them?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should look at. As *@MrCode* a few moments ago, make sure your selector is right. If `#letter-w` is an anchor tag, then `#letter-w a` is probably the wrong selector.

Secondly, [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is an asynchronous call. Move `$('#output').html(html);` inside the success callback to prevent it from executing before the call returns.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#letter-w a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON('widget.json', function (data) {
            var html = '';
            html += data.widget.debug;
            html += data.widget.window.title;
            html += data.widget.window.name;
            $('#output').html(html);
        });
    });
});
```